# get binding names except to_date pattern

Tags: java, sql, regex

I'm working on an java application with database connection. I have a query with bindings like

```
select name from employee where salary >= :sal
```

To get the names of each binding I have

```
List<String> getParameterNames(String query) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":[^\\s\\%\\?']+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(query);
    // without duplications
    Set<String> bindings = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        bindings.add(m.group().substring(1));
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(bindings);
}
```

The user can define an own value for each binding. The query and the values (with their name) are stored at the database. The query is also executed at the database via `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` so I cannot use JDBC. This works fine but I get some trouble if the query contains a date format like

```
select name from employee where hire_date >= to_date(':date', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

With my code I get `date` (correct) and `MI:SS` (incorrect) as bindings.

How can I exclude this date pattern to get the bindings?

Comment: Out of curiosity, will there be multiple bindings in a statement? I know very little about SQL, but I might be able to help with the regex part.

Comment: Also, is using `:date` in single quotes allowed? If it works like a variable, then it should be `to_date(:date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder yes. There may be more bindings. It is also possible to have one binding name multiple times inside. But this is solved by the `Set`

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder The query and the parameter values (and the corresponding binding name) are stored in the database. The query is also executed in the database via `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. I tried without single quotes and got an ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. If it may help to remove the single quotes I can check what I can do at the database.

Answer (score 0):

This might not what you are looking for but you could take a look at spring-jdbc `NamedParameterUtils.parseSqlStatement()` method instead. Unfortunately it returns a `ParsedSql` object which methods are not accessible outside of `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam` package.

```
String sql = "select name from employee where hire_date >= to_date(:date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";
ParsedSql parsedSql = NamedParameterUtils.parseSqlStatement(sql);
List<String> paramNames = parsedSql.getParameterNames();
```

The `':date'` doesn't look like a valid parameter name. It's just a SQL string with `:date` value. Normally one is not supposed to quote the named parameter as the whole point of using them is to let the framework figure out proper escaping based on their type. Could it be that you are writing your own framework for handling named parameters?

Comment: The query and the parameter values (and the corresponding binding name) are stored in the database. The query is also executed in the database via EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. I tried without single quotes and got an ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. If it may help to remove the single quotes I can check what I can do at the database.